# Sql server full text search for a list of words

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I am struggling with the expression syntax of sql server full-text-search feature.

I have a list of user "words" that need to be found in a column of my table:

```
SELECT DocumentNode, DocumentSummary  
FROM Production.Document  
WHERE CONTAINS(DocumentSummary, '"word1" OR "word2"')
```

Is there an efficiect way to do this for a list of x-number words?
Something better than:

```
'"word1" OR "word2" ... OR "wordx"'
```

**UPDATE:**
Let me clarify that my table (for the example here - Production.Document) has several milions of records, so I need the query to have the best performance possible. Also the query might execute some thousands of times per day. I am writting this to explain why the LIKE queries is not an option.

PS: If there is any alternative approach I am missing (other than full-text-search), please do tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do it with CONTAINS as CONTAINS only takes a column as the first parameter and not the second. However, you could put your words in a table and then use dynamic sql to execute your query:

```
Declare @WordTable table
     (Id int primary key,
      Word varchar(25))

Insert @WordTable values (1, 'word1')
Insert @WordTable values (2, 'word2')
Insert @WordTable values (3, 'word3')

DECLARE @Words VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @Words = STUFF ((
        SELECT '"' + Word + '" OR '
        FROM @WordTable
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 0, '')

--drop the last OR
  SELECT  @Words = SUBSTRING(@Words, 0, LEN(@Words) - 2)

  DECLARE @Query VARCHAR(MAX)
  SELECT  @Query = 'SELECT DocumentNode, DocumentSummary  
                    FROM Production.Document  
                    WHERE CONTAINS(DocumentSummary, ''' + @Words +''')'

  EXEC(@Query)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to find **all** the words in list, use 'LIKE' operator like this:

```
SELECT Document.Node, Document.Summary
FROM Production.Document
WHERE Document.Summary LIKE '%word1%'
  AND Document.Summary LIKE '%word2%'
```

On the other hand, if you need to look for **any** word in list just change logical operation to OR. Hope, it will help :)

Comment: Thank you John, yet I need to avoid "LIKE", because my table will have several millions of records, so this will be very expensive. I will update my question to make it clear..